# How to fix Ubuntu not working with a KVM

Tags: system-installation

I have an older machine that I wanted to install Ubuntu on as a "toy" machine.  It originally had Windows Vista which worked just fine with my KVM.  In fact, the old machine is one of three I have on the KVM.  All work fine.
All of the installs listed below were replacement installs... ie... Ubuntu was the only operating system on the machine.
Initially, I attemped to install 12.04 and kept getting a message that Ubuntu could not successfully detect my monitor, vid card, keyboard mouse.  The install did continue. After the install completed, the same message popped up when starting from the hard drive and desktop did not start... just command line linux.
Ok... I installed 11.04 and during hard drive boot the screen would just go black.  Next I tried 13.04 and got the message again during install.
So... I skipped the KVM and connected the monitor directly to the machine... bingo... 13.04 installed fine and a reboot from the hard drive and everything seemed just peachy.
Ok... acid test... the KVM was reconnected and a reboot from the hard drive attempted. The screen goes black, I can hear the Ubuntu drums, and the monitor simply remains black.
Since the KVM worked just fine with Windows... I have no reason to believe its a hardware problem.
Any ideas out there?  (and obviously I am a rube with linux and Ubuntu)
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Windows, Ubuntu tries to detect the video modes supported by the monitor and automatically choose the best one (for a TFT display, this would be the native resolution).

I have had similar issues with a KVM which would cause Ubuntu to choose 1024×768 on a 1280×1024 TFT and not let me change the setting. When I hooked up the monitor directly to the PC, I got the correct resolution.

Apparently, there are a bunch of KVMs out there (presumably mostly older ones) which do not correctly pass extra signals which the OS uses to get the supported video modes from the display.

I don't have a complete solution to offer, as I simply threw out my KVM since I didn't really need it. The best approach would probably be to manually force a particular resolution on the X server.

Try searching this site for "force resolution" or "force video mode". My attempts to edit the X config file back then were not successful; some answers here suggest passing an option to GRUB – maybe that helps.